# Getting error as invalid escape character in java program to write to the file

Tags: java, file

This is a simple java program which is been made to write to the files but when i look at this in my eclipse i get the following error.

```
> Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \' 
> \\ )
```

java code is

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileWrite
{

  public void writeFile()
  {
    FileOutputStream fos;
    DataOutputStream dos;

    try {

      File file= new File("D:\folder1\folder2\test.txt");
      fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
      dos=new DataOutputStream(fos);
      dos.writeInt(2333);
      dos.writeChars("Hello World");

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: try `File file= new File("D:\\folder1\\folder2\\test.txt");`

Comment: Thanks a lot ANS

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the `\`(s) in your `File` path.

```
File file= new File("D:\\folder1\\folder2\\test.txt");`
```

Comment: Or just use / instead \.

Comment: Thank you Elliott, this solves my issue.